# IIS SSL Binding working for some users and others getting access denied

Tags: ssl, iis, binding

We have recently changed the SSL certificate as it got expired. but after changing some users are able to access the static content from the website. but, users getting message window to select certificate and then after selection access denied message is shown.

what can be the issue ? as its working completely fine for some users. it worked for one user after restarting the iis. but some users are still facing the issue

Comment: It's your domain administrators/network administrators' responsibility to analyze further with on the machines, such as what client certificates such users have and what certificates are trusted by the server. Not a programming question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: When you renewed server side certificate, did you renew client side certificate and let users get it? After that, you also need to clear users' cache and cookie. So let users access site through browser incognito windows.